# Tool to minify java script using a build order

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2010, minify

I have some Javascript files I would like to minify and combine into one file.  However since the order they appear is essential to the site not crashing. The simple solution would be to number them, however I do not have that option so I think I need a way to specify the order of the files in some sort of text file and

A: reference that in some sort of post build event in Visual Studio 2010 or

B: use some kind of standalone product to minify and combine the files.

Obviously the post build event would be preferable however that is not a requirement.

Thought? Suggestions?

Comment: have you considered RequireJS?

Comment: Thanks, I have not used ReuireJs before, does it allow me to  specify the order of the js files I want to minify and combine?  I will check it out.

Comment: RequireJS allows you to load script libraries as modules, so if script A depends on script B, it will *wait* until B is loaded. Not sure if that helps, maybe I misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not use Visual Studio - but I have read of the following tool in the past:

http://chirpy.codeplex.com/

In the documentation section there is an example how to integrate it in your Visual Studio project:

http://www.weirdlover.com/2010/07/18/chirpy-attains-godlike-abilities-in-version-1-0-0-4/

Comment: Thanks for this I am looking at it now.  Any chance you know if the tool keeps the js files in the order they need to be?  Not sure how it would know unless it would order them by file name which is not what I want at all.

Comment: this looks to be the answer I was looking for that for the help.